# Google Maps click to drag not working

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using this super basic code to add a google maps to my site:

```
var map;
function initMaps(latIn, longIn, htmltext) {
    var LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latIn, longIn);
    var Options = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: LatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapStatic"), Options);

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: LatLng, 
        map: map
    });

    marker.setMap(map);
    map.enableDragging(); 
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMaps);
```

The map is displaying fine, but for some reason I can't drag it around, is it possible that some other piece of javascript is doing this?
I look around, but didn't find anything that could cause a problem.

Comment: Check your javascript console for errors.

Comment: Does that code work? What location is the map centred on?

Comment: That code works, it's centered on the location I pass to the function (on a later stage) and there are no javascript errors

Comment: So this isn't all the relevant code, then.

Comment: The other one is just initMaps(22.2852635000, 114.1400092000, 'some string');, but that's not really relevatant

Comment: Your `addDomListener` runs the `initMaps` function with no parameters, and it calls `enableDragging()` which is not a Version 3 method. However, neither should be fatal. Maps are draggable by default, and your code as stated *does* produce a draggable map (I tried it) so something else is causing the map not to be draggable.

Comment: I tried the same code in an empty document too and that works fine, would there be any way of finding out what causes this not to be dragable? I'm using this source: http://phpsqlrealty.com/demo/Listing/Condo-Townhome-Row+Home-Co-Op/11-2+Bedroom+Condo.html (click on map), it seems to have the same problem there